# Capture function key events (F1-F12) with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, keydown, keyup

How can I listen for key-press events on function keys ( <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> *etc.* ) with ExtJS?

I am trying to activate a trigger field with the <kbd>F8</kbd> key.

I've tried overriding the `isSpecialKey` method in order to add a *"specialKey"* event with no success - I've also tried to use `Key.map` but that did not trigger anything either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: F8 should be ok, but some F-keys can't be captured, F5 everywhere and F1 in chrome for example.

Comment: @dandavis I think that's OS dependent rather than just browser specific - I'm currently on my Mac and F1 through F12 can be caught without issue in Chrome but you're right - it's worth considering that they often have other uses in different environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the key-code of the event against the known key-code for a particular function key.  For convenience these exist as pre-defined static variables on the [`Ext.event.Event`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.event.Event) class in version **5.x** and [`Ext.EventObject`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.EventObject) in version **4.x** (in either case the class / prototype is accessible via the `self` property on the event instance itself).

```
Ext.getBody().on('keydown', function(ev){
    if(ev.getKey() === ev.self.F8)
        Ext.Msg.show({ msg: 'F8 pressed!' });
});
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/k99) - note that the component you attach the listener to should have focus.

                
(in this example the application window)

Comment: Great @Digigizmo !!!! That works. I just have to change few things:

    initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;
            me.callParent(arguments);

            me.on('boxready', function () {
                    me.on('keydown', function (me, ev) {
                        if (ev.getKey() === ev.F8)
                            Ext.Msg.show({ msg: 'F8 pressed!' });
                    });
            });
        }